# How do I mock a Func<> using Machine.Fakes (Moq)?

Tags: c#, moq, mspec, machine.fakes

I'm trying to test some code I've written have run in to issues trying to mock a func using Machine.Fakes (which uses Moq under the hood). See the code below for an example.

```cs
public class RoutingEngine : IRoutingEngine
{
    private readonly IMessageRouters _messageRouters; 

    public RoutingEngine(IMessageRouters messageRouters)
    {
        _messageRouters = messageRouters; 
    }

    public void Route<T>(T inbound)
    {
        var messageRouters = _messageRouters.Where(x => x.CanRoute(inbound)); 
        foreach(var router in messageRouters)
            router.Route(inbound); 
    }
}

public class MessageRouters : IMessageRouters
{
    public IList<IMessageRouter> _routers = new List<IMessageRouter>();

    public IEnumerable<IMessageRouter> Where(Func<IMessageRouter, bool> func)
    {
        return _routers.Where(func); 
    }

    public void Add(IMessageRouter messageRouter)
    {
        _routers.Add(messageRouter); 
    }
}
```

And the test is here

```cs
public class when_routing_a_message_with_fakes : WithSubject<RoutingEngine>
{
    Establish that = () =>
    {
        Message = new MyMessage{ SomeValue= 1, SomeOtherValue = 11010 };
        Router = The<IMessageRouter>();
        Router.WhenToldTo(x => x.CanRoute(Message)).Return(true);             
        The<IMessageRouters>().WhenToldTo(x => x.Where(router => router.CanRoute(Message))).Return(new List<IMessageRouter> { Router }); 
    };

    Because of = () => Subject.Route(Message);

    It should_do_route_the_message = () => Subject.WasToldTo(x => x.Route(Param.IsAny<MyMessage>()));

    static MyMessage Message;
    static IMessageRouter Router;
}
```

I get an unsupported expression for the above so I changed the where method on the `IMessageRouters` to the following:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IMessageRouter> Where(Expression<Func<IMessageRouter, bool>> func)
{
    return _routers.Where(func.Compile()); 
}
```

Now I get this error

> Object instance was not created by Moq.
>     Parameter name: mocked

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

So I tried writing another test without machine.fakes, as per [Mocking methods with Expression<Func<T,bool>> parameter using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655545/mocking-methods-with-expressionfunct-bool-parameter-using-moq). Turns out it's an obvious problem. The func used in the real RoutingEngine is not being mocked

```cs
The<IMessageRouters>()
    .WhenToldTo(x => x.Where(router => router.CanRoute(Param.IsAny<ProcessSkuCostUpdated>())))
    .Return(new List<IMessageRouter> {Router});
```

The above has no bearing on the Where being executed at runtime and can't be as the func is compiled down to a private method at compile time. Seems like to mock the func, I need to push it up to an interface. Smells though as I'm pushing up internal behavior purely for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your test code:

1. The expression you use for setting up the `Where()` call on `IMessageRouters` is too explicit. It should not care about what exact function is passed.
2. You are verifying whether `Route()` has been called on the `Subject`. Instead you should verify whether the `Message` has been passed to the `IMessageRouter`.

As an additional improvement, you can omit the `Router` field and use `The<IMessageRouter>()` directly.

```
[Subject(typeof(RoutingEngine))]
public class when_routing_a_message_with_fakes : WithSubject<RoutingEngine>
{
    Establish that = () =>
    {
        Message = new MyMessage { SomeValue = 1, SomeOtherValue = 11010 };
        The<IMessageRouter>().WhenToldTo(x => x.CanRoute(Message)).Return(true);
        The<IMessageRouters>().WhenToldTo(x => x.Where(Param<Func<IMessageRouter, bool>>.IsAnything))
            .Return(new List<IMessageRouter> { The<IMessageRouter>() });
    };

    Because of = () => Subject.Route(Message);

    It should_route_the_message = () =>
        The<IMessageRouter>().WasToldTo(x => x.Route(Message));

    static MyMessage Message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a way to avoid mocking the `Func<>` at all. I hope it's interesting to you :) Why not forget about the generalized `Where(Func<>)` method and provide the specific query method. You own the inbound messages and the router(s).

```
public class MessageRouters : IMessageRouters
{
    public IList<IMessageRouter> _routers = new List<IMessageRouter>();

    public IEnumerable<IMessageRouter> For<T>(T inbound)
    {
        return _routers.Where(x => x.CanRoute(inbound)); 
    }

    public void Add(IMessageRouter messageRouter)
    {
        _routers.Add(messageRouter); 
    }
}
```

The class under test becomes simpler (in signature, no `Func<>`).

```
public class RoutingEngine : IRoutingEngine
{
    private readonly IMessageRouters _messageRouters; 

    public RoutingEngine(IMessageRouters messageRouters)
    {
        _messageRouters = messageRouters; 
    }

    public void Route<T>(T inbound)
    {
        var messageRouters = _messageRouters.For(inbound); 
        foreach(var router in messageRouters)
            router.Route(inbound); 
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you don't need to inspect the actual instance of the inbound message either, maybe you can get away with just a `Type` check, like

```
public IEnumerable<IMessageRouter> For<T>() { ... }
```

and

```
var messageRouters = _messageRouters.For<T>();
```

You don't have to mock any `Func<>`s now and you can just do an assert-was-called (or however that looks in Moq).